# How do I keep an OpenCV namedWindow with a HWND handle on top of all other windows in Windows 8?

Tags: c++, winapi, opencv, windows-8

The title pretty much says it all. I've created a window with namedWindow() and filled it with a matrix. I then assign it to a HWND using cvGetWindowHandle() so that I can use the Windows function SetWindowPos(). Using this I'm supposed to be able to set the flags HWND_TOPMOST, SWP_NOMOVE and SWP_NOSIZE in order to keep it above all other windows even when I click on a window behind it.

I've either misread something here and got the wrong idea or I believe that the problem might be the fact that I have upgraded to Windows 8 and they have deprecated this function or something. Is there another way to go about this?

Comment: Such windows that do not go away when told to or gain focus when not given by user are considered extremely annoying by users. Application told to die should die in 5 seconds.

Comment: @ÖöTiib I'm creating a kinect application where it is more beneficial to the user to be able to see the viewer while in use

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a setup to try this in c++, but I wanted to do something similar in python so I ended up using a python win32 library.  With a combination of the following calls (I assume you can find them for win32 in c++), I always managed to get the screen on top. But it didn't stay there. I had to bring it up when I wanted it.

```
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)  # I use just this. apparently it can trigger permission error but I never had a problem with it
win32gui.SetFocus(hwnd)  # apparently doesn't trigger error without permission like setforegroundwindow
win32gui.BringWindowToTop(hwnd)  # not sure if this helps any
win32gui.SetActiveWindow(hwnd) #not sure if this helps any
```

Comment: The only one of these that is working for me is SetForegroundWindow() but it also sets it as the active window meaning that I can't use anything behind it. I don't suppose there is any way to do that is there?

Comment: Indeed I struggled with the behavior quite a lot. It seems inconsistent but probably because I have no experience with win32. Perhaps you could use SetForegroundWindow and then use one of the others to change focus back to your application without bringing it to the front?